# Can't connect to MongoDB replicaSet

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-replica-set, changestream

I tried to use MongoDB change streams and i need to use replicaSets but mongoDB doesn't let me use it because of load balancer i tried to set it false like this:

```
mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}/?replicaSet=rs0&loadBalanced=false&readPreference=secondaryPreferred
```

but its still giving me same error :

```
MongoParseError: loadBalanced option not supported with a replicaSet option
```

Here is my connection code:

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}/?replicaSet=rs0&loadBalanced=false&readPreference=secondaryPreferred`;
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    await client.connect();
```

Comment: Have you tried removing it (`loadBlanced=false`) from the connection string altogether?

Comment: Yes, its still giving the same error @user20042973

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you don't configure `loadBalanced` at all, you see the same exception. If so, the reason for it is that your server has loadBalanced option configured in [txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record) records. When a driver gets these records after resolving SRV, it implicitly adds them to connection string.
IE server/driver expects working in load balancing mode which doesn't support replica set option. `nslookup` should help with checking it. I'm not 100% sure, but I think something like this: `nslookup -q=TXT yoururl.com` should help to see it